# show Arabic Numerals

Tags: java, docx, docx4j

my question is using docx4j when i convert docx to pdf in my local it fine show English numerals like "0123456789" but when i convert other machine it show arabic numerals like "٠‎١‎٢‎٣‎٤‎٥‎٦‎٧‎٨‎٩‎".

Much appreciated,
my code is

```
    String regex = null;
    PhysicalFonts.setRegex(regex);

    FOSettings foSettings = Docx4J.createFOSettings();
    foSettings.setWmlPackage(wordMLPackage);

    Docx4J.toFO(foSettings, os, Docx4J.FLAG_NONE);
    logger.info(" Successfully Convert into PDF ");
```

Comment: Please put your docx on http://ndoc.it and post a link here.  If you open the PDFs in Acrobat, what fonts does it say are in use?  Are the fonts used on your local machine installed on the other one?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8pxsroimb60jsiz/Information.docx?dl=0 my docx file link, i have checked in pdf other machine is same fonts

Answer (score 0):

Check docx4j.properties:

```
# These affect the output of numbers in Arabic; see further RunFontSelector
# For further discussion, please see http://www.docx4java.org/forums/pdf-output-f27/arabic-number-digits-in-pdf-output-t1826.html
# Value can be 'Context'|'National'
docx4j.MicrosoftWindows.Region.Format.Numbers.NativeDigits=National
# Value can be 'Hindi'|'Context'|'Arabic'|'System'; default is Arabic ie 1234
docx4j.MicrosoftWord.Numeral=Arabic
```